# Notification: Send a message to everyone who has downloaded my app

Tags: azure, push-notification, win-universal-app, uwp

I am developing a UWP app and after downloading the app I want to send my users a particular messages after few days of downloading my app. And the message can be different each time depending on what message I want to give them.

So where should I start? Would be great if there is a sample out there or a tutorial link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the message at the same time for all your users you need to use **push notifications**. 
[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/) is a great tutorial on how to get started with that. (WP 8.1 is identical to UWP in this case).
You can also check the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) on push notifications.

However, if you want to send messages to each user at certain times based on when they open the app (say, 2 days after they download the app, 5 days after they download the app, etc), you could also use a [Local notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts). You can either hard-code those messages, or obtain them from a web-service.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Engagement can do that and much more.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-engagement/

> #### Value-added push and communications
>
> Mobile Engagement works flawlessly with native push-notification gateways, such as Google GCM, Apple APNS, or Microsoft WNS. It lets you send targeted notifications, polls, and in-app notifications with text and rich HTML payloads. Personalize the notifications with data captured from app usage like user names and genders. Send multi-language notifications targeting the specific locales of the app users. Schedule notifications in advance and finally get feedback on their effectiveness by getting statistics about how many users viewed the notifications and took action.